# call back from slider change not updating my plot in bokeh in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, bokeh

I am working on a Bokeh visualisation of datasets across a number of categories. The initial part of the visual is a donut chart of the categories showing the total number of items in each category. I am trying to get the chart to update based on a min-max range using `RangeSlider` - but the chart does not update.

The input source for the glyphs is the output from a `create_cat_df` - which is returned as a Pandas DF, then converted into a CDS using `ColumnDataSource.from_df()`.

The chart appears okay when this code is run (with slider alongside) - but moving the slider changes nothing.

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283912/how-can-i-link-the-slider-to-update-my-plot-in-bokeh-while-in-a-jupyter-notebook#).
The answer here was useful in putting me onto `from_df` - but even after following this I can't get the code to work.

```
def create_doc(doc):

    ### INPUT widget
    cat_min_max = RangeSlider(start=0, end=1000, value=[0, 1000], step=1, title="Category min-max items (m)")

    inputs = column(cat_min_max, width=300, height=850)  # in preparation for multiple widgets

    ### Tooltip & tools
    TOOLTIPS_2 = [("Item", "$item")            # a sample
               ]

    hover_2 = HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS_2, names = ['cat'])
    tools = [hover_2, TapTool(), WheelZoomTool(), PanTool(), ResetTool()] 


    ### Create Figure
    p = figure(plot_width=width, plot_height=height, title="",
        x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None,
        x_range=(-420, 420), y_range=(-420, 420), 
        min_border=0, outline_line_color=None,
        background_fill_color="#f0e1d2",
              tools = tools, toolbar_location="left")

    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

    # taptool
    url = "https://google.com/"    #dummy URL
    taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
    taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

    # create cat_source CDS using create_cat_df function (returns pandas df) and 'from_df' method
    cat_source = ColumnDataSource.from_df(create_cat_df(cat_min_max.value[0], cat_min_max.value[1]))

    ## plot category  wedges
    p.annular_wedge('centre_x', 'centre_y', 'inner', 'outer', 'start', 'end', color='color', 
                    alpha='alpha', direction='clock', source=cat_source, name='cat')

    r = row([inputs, p])

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        cat_source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(create_cat_df(cat_min_max.value[0], cat_min_max.value[1]))

    cat_min_max.on_change('value', callback)  

    doc.add_root(r)


show(create_doc)
```

I would like to get the code working and the chart updating. There are a number more glyphs & different data layers to layer in, but I want to get the basics working first.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html) the `ColumnDataSource.from_df()` method returns a dictionary while you need to pass a `ColumnDatSource` to the `source` argument in `p.annular_wedge(source = cat_source)`

So instead of:

```
cat_source = ColumnDataSource.from_df(create_cat_df(cat_min_max.value[0], cat_min_max.value[1]))
```

You should do:

```
cat_source = ColumnDataSource(data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(create_cat_df(cat_min_max.value[0], cat_min_max.value[1])))
```

Comment: Thanks Getting the `ColumnDataSource` syntax right helped move in the right direction - but on reading again I realised I asked the question badly.
I have provided a much more specific question (with wholly self contained code & data) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191083/bokeh-button-callback-only-partially-working)
In this example the button is partially working - but only changes the glyphs once (not subsequently).

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, using the syntax `df.to_dict(orient='list')` seems to do a better job than `ColumnDataSource.from_df`.