# bokeh button callback only partially working

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am plotting a complex interactive donut chart in bokeh. The code below is a simplification of a component of this chart.

I have a function which compiles a dataframe of data for the donut, and then converts it to a CDS. This data is then plotted as annular wedges.
A radiobutton group should trigger a switch to a different dataframe (as CDS), and replot the annular wedge glyphs.

The example provide (for Jupyter Lab) works in one direction. When initially plotted the `button.active == 0` (outer_1). When outer_2 is selected, the chart correctly changes to plot the second dataframe (cds).

But when the outer_1 button is pressed, the glyphs do not change back. The callback is triggered - as the title changes. But the glyphs do not change.

Why are the glyphs not changing in subsequent button presses / callbacks?

I've read a few similar SO posts, and also reviewed a number of bokeh examples (the weather example [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/weather) is similar)

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi

from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.layouts import column, row 
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'start':[pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2],
                   'end' :[pi/2+1.5, pi+1.5, (3*pi/2)+1.5],
                   'inner': [100,100,100],
                   'outer': [200,200,200],
                   'color':['red','green','blue']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'start':[pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2],
                   'end' :[pi/2+1, pi+1, (3*pi/2)+1],
                   'inner': [100,100,100],
                   'outer': [250,300,350],
                    'color':['orange','gray','purple']})

data_1 = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
data_2 = ColumnDataSource(data=df_2)


def create_doc(doc):

    button = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["outer_1", "outer_2"], active=0)

    inputs = column(button)

    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600, title="data_1",
                   x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None,
                   x_range=(-300, 300), y_range=(-300, 300),
                   min_border=0, outline_line_color=None,
                   background_fill_color='white', toolbar_location="above")

    circle = p.circle(0,0, radius=100, fill_alpha=0, line_color='grey', line_alpha=0.4)

    source = [data_1, data_2][button.active]

    segments = p.annular_wedge(0,0,'inner', 'outer', 'start', 'end', color='color', alpha=0.6, source=source, name='segments')


    r = row (inputs,p)


    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if button.active == 1:
            p.title.text = 'data_2  {}'.format(button.active)
            source.data.update(data_2.data)
        elif button.active == 0:
            p.title.text = 'data_1 {}'.format(button.active)
            source.data.update(data_1.data)

    button.on_change('active', callback)

    doc.add_root(r)


show(create_doc)
```

The glpyhs change successfully once, but not again, although the changing title text (on button presses) indicate that the buttons & callback continue to work partially.

Comment: Please note that this a very simplified example. In the real app, the screening and selection criteria for determining the data to be used are complex, and need to use a pandas df.
Once that has been done, I can convert into a cds (as in the weather example linked) for the plotting.
So I really need to understand what it is about exactly this approach that is causing a problem. I can't avoid using the df as the main source point for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Why converting to `DataFrame` knowing that internally the data of ColumnDataSource is a dictionary? The following code works fine for Bokeh v1.1.0

```
from math import pi
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc, Row, Column, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import RadioButtonGroup

output_notebook()

data1 = {'start':[pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2],
        'end' :[pi/2+1.5, pi+1.5, (3*pi/2)+1.5],
        'inner': [100,100,100],
        'outer': [200,200,200],
        'color':['red','green','blue']}

data2 = {'start':[pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2],
         'end' :[pi/2+1, pi+1, (3*pi/2)+1],
         'inner': [100,100,100],
         'outer': [250,300,350],
         'color':['orange','gray','purple']}

def create_doc(doc):

    button = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["outer_1", "outer_2"], active=0)

    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600, title="data_1",
                   x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None,
                   x_range=(-300, 300), y_range=(-300, 300),
                   min_border=0, outline_line_color=None,
                   background_fill_color='white', toolbar_location="above")

    circle = p.circle(0,0, radius=100, fill_alpha=0, line_color='grey', line_alpha=0.4)
    segments = p.annular_wedge(0,0,'inner', 'outer', 'start', 'end', color='color', alpha=0.6, source = data1, name='segments')

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if button.active == 0:
            print '000'
            p.title.text = 'data_1 {}'.format(button.active)
            segments.data_source.data = data1
        elif button.active == 1:
            print '111'
            p.title.text = 'data_2  {}'.format(button.active)
            segments.data_source.data = data2 

    button.on_change('active', callback)

    inputs = Column(button)
    r = Row(inputs,p)
    doc.add_root(r)

show(create_doc)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a greatly simplified example. The actual data frames are large and the selection criteria are complex. But the principle is what is represented here - the need to apply changes to a df converted into a CDS.

Comment: Also - the link a referenced above to the bokeh weather example appears to follow a similar process:
- Select data using a df
- Convert df to CDS
- use callback syntax in my example to change plot

So I am just trying to work out why my example doesn't work as that one does.